# How do I change x-axis label spacing in function gf_plot in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have plotted a time-series plot using gf_line. All I need is to change the x-axis labels to display a tick and label for every 1 year rather than every 5. This is currently my code:

```
gf_line(SWH ~ t1 ,data=newdf)%>%  
gf_labs( title ="significant wave height against time",y= "significant wave height (m)", x="time" )
```

I would greatly appreciate your help with formatting the axis. Thank you!

Comment: Could you include the data: paste the data frame into the question using `dput(newdf)`?

Comment: Try adding `+  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "5 years")`